# HootSuite Channel doesn't appear in my list in IFTTT account

Tags: facebook, buffer, google-plus, hootsuite

My company where I work , has already a profile in Facebook that it's to share post , photos, events, news and so on. Now they want to sync Facebook post to Google+. The sync must be done from Facebook to Google+( because the person that manages the page, is used to Facebook). As we know Google+ does not have an API to write , its API is readonly. So I took a reading and I find out that there is an option using Buffer, IFTTT and HootSuite considering this article:

http://mrbhatt.com/blog/tech/how_to_post_to_google_plus_1.html

The problem is in my list of trigger channel I cannot find anything about hootsuite. Can anybody help how can I configure the HootSuite, or another way how to achieve this.

Comment: Hootsuite was removed from IFTTT - https://forum.hootsuite.com/hootsuite/topics/hello_i_cant_autorize_hootsuite_channel_for_ifttt_could_not_activate_channel_ifttt_gives_me?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all&topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Breply_id%5D=13383327#reply_13383327

Comment: thanks, do I have any other options to post to Google Plus from Facebook?

Comment: Maybe with the Buffer channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , get a bufferapp account. `bufferapp.com`. Then, sign in to gmail, or google accounts at `gmail.com`. GO back to bufferapp, and add `Google+` into your account, and give it permission when asked.

Then go `ifttt.com` , set up account. Log in , select channels. Add bufferapp. Then ADD social media of choice , You can use GOOGLE+, Facebook, tumblr, twitter, etc.. there is a bunch .  Add Soical media of choice, or even add an RSS feed to ifttt.com ..

Now go to my recipes (yes recipes) .. then create a new recipe ..pick GOOGLE+ or whatever, then tell it what you want , then pick bufferapp and tell it what you want..

You can also browse recipes on `ifttt.com` , and there you can lookup bufferapp ones .. th right one will show up

Comment: thanks, even it was an old post, I find it really useful at this moment, e very nice explanation.